# Why do slackware packages recreate symlinks after installation?

Tags: package-management, symlink, slackware

Reading through slackware's makepkg script, I saw that rather than putting symlinks directly into the package, it deletes them and generates a script called doinst.sh that recreates them after installing the package.

Is there any reason why the links have to be recreated post-install? It seems like an unnecessary step to me.

Comment: Technically it's just how `makepkg` manual recommends to do. You could do without this script and leave symlinks in the package by saying `makepkg -l n` when creating a package. As for why my guess it was a means for reducing package size, imho.

Comment: The other reason is that you can install a package to a fake root with `installpkg -root /tmp/fakeroot`. With this having symlinks in the package won't make much sense, it would be easier to create them manually, imho.

Comment: With relative links that wouldn't be a problem, but I understand some packages may create absolute links.